# Cannot unlink temporary SQLite file

Tags: php, sqlite, doctrine-orm

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/) but I got stuck on moment when I need to unlink testing database on `tearDown()` (or whenever I need to) - I get the message that file is busy and cannot be unlinked.

`lsof` tells me that `php` process is locking that file. Is it normal? How to delete these file during tests execution?

Comment: Do you need permission to modify files??

Comment: Permissions are fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in shared folder permissions - I'm sharing my `DOC_ROOT` folder with Virtual Machine on which is running Apache. If I change path to temporary file which stores SQLite DB everything works fine.

Comment: This also lead me to figuring out why I could not `unlink()` files in a Vagrant/Virtualbox VM after manipulating them.  First copying the files to /tmp in my virtual machine and then working with them there solved the problem.